# My navigation is doing something that I have not told it to do?

Tags: html, nav

When I go to look at the product of my code it shows biology above the rest of the navigation, and I want it to be in line with the rest. I can't seem to figure out why it is doing that and would like some help figuring it out. Here's the code.
*edit: I have added my css to the post below.Thank you for your help!

```html
  <nav>
    <a href="index.html">Main</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Algebra</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="algebra1.html">Algebra 1</a>
        <a href="algebra2.html">Algebra 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Calculus</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="calculus1.html">Calculus 1</a>
        <a href="calculus2.html">Calculus 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Physics</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="physics1.html">Physics 1</a>
        <a href="physics2.html">Physics 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Biology</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="generalbiology.html">General Biology</a>
        <a href="microbiology.html">Microbiology</a>
      </div>
    <div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Chemistry</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="chemistry1.html">Chemistry 1</a>
        <a href="chemistry2.html">Chemistry 2</a>
        <a href="organicchemistry1.html">Organic Chemistry 1</a>
        <a href="organicchemistry2.html">Organic Chemistry 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Test Prep</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="mcatprep.html">MCAT Prep</a>
        <a href="usmleprep.html">USMLE Prep</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

````
body {
  background-color: #328D8D;
}

/* Header 1 */
h1 {
  font: Georgia;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}

/* Header 2 */
h2 {
  font: Georgia;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* Navigation */
nav {
  background-color: #226666;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #226666;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #226666;
  color: white;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #226666;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #226666;}```
````

Comment: Where is your `css` ?

Comment: Please provide your css. Edit your post accordingly.